# Azure Blob storage very slow read time

Tags: c#, azure, json.net, azure-blob-storage

I am saving JSON data as Block Blobs in Azure Blob Storage - Standard Tier. The file size is 14.5MB, it contains about 25,000 objects of OLHC data I access the blob from an Azure Function located in the same region. The code simply reads the blob for deserialization, but it takes 20-40 seconds. Is there something I missed?

```
    public static async Task<Stream> GetBlob(string ConnectionString, string ContainerName, string Path)
    {
        BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClient(ConnectionString, ContainerName, Path);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        try
        {
            await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(ms);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return ms;
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ms.Dispose();
            throw;
        }        
    }
```

And I request the blob in the function

```
        log.LogInformation($"Begin Downloading Blob ");
        using (Stream blob = await Core.Azure.Blob.GetBlob(blobString, "containerName", fileName))
        {
            log.LogInformation($"End Downloading Blob ");
            log.LogInformation($"Begin Reading Blob ");
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(blob))
            {
                string json = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                log.LogInformation($"Begin Deserialize Blob ");
                sticks = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyModel>>(json);
                log.LogInformation($"End Deserialize Blob ");
            }
        }
        log.LogInformation($"{symbol} End Get Blob ");
```

Check Blob Exist Function

```
    public static async Task<bool> CheckExists(string ConnectionString, string ContainerName, string Path)
    {
        BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClient(ConnectionString, ContainerName, Path);
        return await blobClient.ExistsAsync();
    }
```

This is the result of the timing is up to 47 Seconds

I switch to stream reader and JSON Reader and it drops to 10-30 seconds.. but still, that's a very long time

I have added the timing here

2021-01-09 23:53:26.656 Begin Downloading Blob
2021-01-09 23:53:30.163 End Downloading Blob
2021-01-09 23:53:30.163 Begin Reading Blob
2021-01-09 23:53:37.040 Begin Deserialize Blob
2021-01-09 23:53:49.737 End Deserialize Blob

**Another Run**
*OHLCData.Json 14.44 MB (28,000 rows)*

2021-01-10 12:40:49.970 Begin Check Blob Exists
2021-01-10 12:40:58.962 End Check Blob Exists
2021-01-10 12:40:58.962 Begin Downloading Blob
2021-01-10 12:41:08.181 End Downloading Blob
2021-01-10 12:41:08.187 Begin Reading Blob
2021-01-10 12:41:25.713 Begin Deserialize Blob
2021-01-10 12:41:33.817 End Deserialize Blob
2021-01-10 12:41:33.817 End Get Blob

Comment: `The code simply reads the blob for deserialization,` It doesn't just _read_ it. It also has to download it, correct?

Comment: When you stepped through it / profiled it, which lines of code were the slow bits (so we can focus on that)?

Comment: How long does it take if you use `DownloadAsync` instead?

Comment: The slow bits were reading the stream from Blob and sometimes de-serialization. I switched to streamreader and the result is only slightly better

Comment: Is it faster if you use `string json = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();` rather than `string json = reader.ReadToEnd();`? Given it is in RAM I doubt async is helping much there.

Comment: @mjwills did you mean the other way around? Are you suggesting a blocking method vs async?

Comment: Yep, that is what I meant.

Comment: Did using `ReadToEnd` and / or `DownloadAsync` change those timings? You are running Release build?

Comment: So that run took 23 seconds, and you are seeing 20-47 seconds. Can you show us the timings for a 47 second run (so we can see where the variability is)?

Comment: @TimDavis is the content downloaded from the Azure Blob Storage `UTF-8` encoded ? In that case, you can try to use the new `System.Text.Json` APIs to efficiently deserialize `JSON` content from `UTF-8` encoded binary data. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#deserialize-from-utf-8) for details.

Comment: @TimDavis my point is the following. You can't do much on download times, it depends on the file size, the speed of the network, the speed of Azure servers when your download request arrives, the bandwith and so on... The easiest point of intervention for you is the deserialization task. The new Microsoft library to serialize and deserialize JSON content seems to be really optimized for UTF-8 binary data.

Comment: @TimDavis maybe it's worth trying. You are currently reading the binary data into a string, then you pass the string to the `JSON` deserializer (it seems you are using `Newtonsoft JSON`). Maybe the `System.Text.Json` API can be faster at this step. The only caveat you need to check is the encoding of the downloaded content.

Comment: @EnricoMassone I am serializing and saving the the same data that i'm retrieving using JsonConvert.SerializeObject(). Is there a faster save and retrieve raw objects to disk? There may be multiple concurrent data transfers from same storage account (up to 20 at a time) but Azure says bandwidth is 10Gbs which would eat 20 files in 0.23 seconds

Comment: And why does it take 8 seconds just to see if the blob exists?

Comment: @TimDavis I don't know why checking for the blob existence takes so much time. My suggestion is check the encoding of the downloaded data. If it's UTF-8 you can get a byte array from the memory stream content and you can try to deserialize the binary data directly, without converting them to a string before. You can do so by following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#deserialize-from-utf-8)

Comment: You need to use [System.Text.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json/) package to do so

Comment: This is the easiest attempt at the client code level, based on my understanding. That said, usually the IO takes much more time than the CPU bound work, so your next step should be investigating why the Azure Blob Storage is so slow when checking for the blob and downloading it. Have you already tried to open a github issue to the Azure blob storage client repository ? Maybe you can also consider to open a ticket to the Azure support. Both the github issues and the Azure tickets are usually efficiently managed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are downloading the whole blob into memory stream (unnecessary extra memory kill), converting to string and then deserializing it. I would rather do it directly from blob stream in one shot leveraging the [stream support of `Newtonsoft.Json`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#ID2RBToggle) like below to optimize speed and memory use.

```cs
BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClient(ConnectionString, ContainerName, Path);
using (var stream = await blobClient.OpenReadAsync())
using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
using (var jr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
{
    result = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().Deserialize<T>(jr);
}
```

You can also do similar using `System.Text.Json` APIs.

```cs
JsonSerializerOptions Options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
using (var stream = await blobClient.OpenReadAsync())
{
    result = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(stream , Options);
}
```